# Use hive custom outputformat to handle log files

Tags: hadoop, hive, output-formatting

I want to use hive Version 0.7.0 handle the log files and i set the custem inputformat and outputformat. In the inputformat, i replace the "\n" to "@#@", and in the outputformat i want to change back to "\n". After test my inputformat does well but my outputformat doesn't work. I want to know why. Here is the code. Thanks!

```
public class ErrlogOutputFormat, V extends Writable>
    extends HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat {

    public static class CustomRecordWriter implements RecordWriter{

        RecordWriter writer;
        BytesWritable bytesWritable;

        public CustomRecordWriter(RecordWriter writer) {
            this.writer = writer;
            bytesWritable = new BytesWritable();
        }

        @Override
        public void write(Writable w) throws IOException {
            //String str = ((Text) w).toString().replaceAll("@#@","\n");
            String[] str = ((Text) w).toString().split("@#@");
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for(String s:str){
                sb.append(s).append("\n");
            }
            Text txtReplace = new Text(sb.toString());
            System.out.println("------------------------");
            System.out.println(txtReplace.toString());
            System.out.println("------------------------");

            // Get input data
            // Encode
            byte[] output = txtReplace.getBytes();

            bytesWritable.set(output, 0, output.length);

            writer.write(bytesWritable);
        }

        @Override
        public void close(boolean abort) throws IOException {
            writer.close(abort);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public RecordWriter getHiveRecordWriter(JobConf jc, Path finalOutPath,
            Class valueClass, boolean isCompressed,
            Properties tableProperties, Progressable progress)
            throws IOException {

        CustomRecordWriter writer = new CustomRecordWriter(super
                .getHiveRecordWriter(jc, finalOutPath, BytesWritable.class,
                        isCompressed, tableProperties, progress));

        return writer;
    }
}
```

Comment: My hql is : create table hivetest (message STRING)  stored as INPUTFORMAT "com.xh.hiveDW.plugin.errlog.ErrlogInputFormat" OUTPUTFORMAT "com.xh.hiveDW.plugin.errlog.ErrlogOutputFormat";  and when i load the data into table and select message from hivetest, i can't get the result like this:

Comment: 2012-02-09 04:26:14,952 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR com.opensymphony.webwork.dispatcher.ServletDispatcher - Could not execute action
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:96)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)